# How do I control Java/Swing GUI component alignment using NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, alignment

As a NetBeans novice, I'm laying out a pretty simple 2-panel GUI using NetBeans 7.0, and I'm having the craziest time getting some components (JButtons, JLabels, JSlider) to stay where I position them within the enclosing JPanel!

For example, when I drag one of the buttons to the upper left corner of its enclosing panel, I never see any guidelines, and when I release it, it zooms back toward the center of the panel, disturbing the placement of other components, and enlarging both the panel and, ultimately, the JFrame.  It's as if the button somehow imagines itself to be a lot larger, or to need a lot more room around its edges, then it really does.

I hope that's enough information for someone with experience to readily diagnose my problem; otherwise I'll try to answer follow-up questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you learn the Layout specifications and how things fit together before using a GUI builder. You could use your Netbeans as a sophisticated editor with file completion and debugger and write your first Swing code in regular classes, until you get the grasp of things.

Then you will appreciate better the capabilities of the tool.

Netbeans give you a default Free-Design Layout which is very easy to use graphically and although the generated code is kind of weird, the good news is that you will never have to deal with it.

You can add borders to your panels so you can see the behavior when you drag and drop components and resize the panels.

Comment: I'm inclined to take your advice, at least with regard to NetBeans' GUI builder - it isn't novice-friendly.  (I edited the properties of a JList just to remove its five default items, and the widget blew out to twice its former width!  Clearly there's magic here I don't understand.)  As I prefer working in Eclipse, this will also spare me the pain of trying to switch back and forth with NetBeans.

Comment: Eclipse is fine, but the Matisse implementation of Netbeans is unbeatable. As soon as you have learned Layouts well using a GUI builder will enhance your productivity big time! You will then return to Netbeans, unless Eclipse come with an equivalent solution. Matisse is implemented in MyEclipse though.

Comment: Found a not-bad intro to coding Swing textually: (http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/)

Comment: Understanding the nuts and bolts of the components and _especially_ the different Layout Managers is proving to be very valuable.  The above tutorial does a good job of efficiently and progressively introducing the concepts.  (Although the English is pretty sub-par, it's still possible to understand.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the LayoutManager that you wish to use in the JPanel. The default LayoutManager is the FlowLayout and that is responsible for the behaviour that you are experiencing. You may want to try GridBagLayout or BoxLayout for more control over the positioning of components.

Comment: Unfortunately, switching to GridBag or Box just made things worse (admittedly, this was in midstream, which probably isn't the right way to do it).

Answer (score 0):

You first change the Resizable property of that button to false. by default it is true.
for this, select the button, at right hand side's Properties window you'll find that property in Layout group.
Also check the Anchoring is done properly. Sometimes the component you add to left side may be anchored to right or top/bottom. For this right click on the button and go to "anchor" and select the appropriate value.
Hope this helps you.